# React app HashRouter not working on localhost as well as Github User page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, react-router-dom

I'm creating a blog in React to be deployed on **GitHub Pages**.

**Problem**

1. Created my React app and added **BrowserRouter** for navigation, everything was working fine on localhost and the app successfully deployed on the **GitHub Pages**.
2. Even though Home page was accessible on **GitHub Pages**, if I click on any link there was **404 Error**. The problem was **BrowserRouter** does not work with GitHub pages.
3. After some research I added **HashRouter** in my react app as **BrowserRouter** was not working on GitHub pages.
4. With **HashRouter** again Homepage is loaded successfully but if I click on link that should take me from **home to blog** section the expected behaviour should have been something like this  `localhost:3000/#/blog` but the url changes to something like `localhost:3000/blog#/` and I'm still on homepage.
5. Problem 4 is true for both localhost as well as Github Pages
6. But if I manually enter the url `localhost:3000/#/blog` it works perfectly fine and loads the **Blog** component as expected. Similar behaviour on the **GitHub Pages**.

   **Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import HODL from './HODL';
import Header from './Header';
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Jargons from './Jargons';

class Home extends Component {

  render () {

    return (
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HODL} />
          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
          <Route path="/tutorials/javascript" component={JavaScript} />
          <Route path="/tutorials/solidity" component={Solidity} />
          <Route path="/jargons" component={Jargons} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Works same with or without `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}`

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "block-by-block.github.io",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://block-by-block.github.io",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**PS :** Complete source code is available at [Github link](https://github.com/block-by-block/website) and the app is deployed here [React App](https://block-by-block.github.io/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the issue lies in your Header component.
You are using bootstrap which is not compatible with react-router-dom. For more information, kindly look it up on google.

Here is what you should change:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/jargons">
   Jargons that works!
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy it solved the problem on localhost, but now my github deployment isn't working at all, not even the homepage is loading. I noticed even though I have "homepage" specified in my package.json after "npm run deploy" I'm getting "The project was built assuming it is hosted at /. You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json." I think this is what is causing the problem. Hope you can help.

Comment: Your page has full of error in the console, you can enable dev mode to check what the errors say

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<HashRouter basename="/xyz"/>
 <Router component={}>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: It did not work. By the way I think you are trying to say that  I should replace <Router> with <HashRouter>, but I'm importing HashRouter as Router. I'll edit the question to show all imports for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me:
I moved the path="/" to the bottom of the stack of routes

```
      <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
      <Route path="/tutorials/javascript" component={JavaScript} />
      <Route path="/tutorials/solidity" component={Solidity} />
      <Route path="/jargons" component={Jargons} />

      **<Route path="/" exact component={HODL} />**
    </Switch>
```