# Replace BrowserRouter with HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm essentially having the same problem as this: [React app HashRouter not working on localhost as well as Github User page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300429/react-app-hashrouter-not-working-on-localhost-as-well-as-github-user-page)

I used their solution but it only works with the first link I have up. Is there a way to get multiple links to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { Music } from './Music';
import { FullCV } from './FullCV';
import { ContactMe } from './ContactMe';
import { NoMatch } from './NoMatch';
import { NavigationBar } from './components/NavigationBar';
import { Jumbotron } from './components/Jumbotron';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './mycssfile.css';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <div>
       <Helmet>
         <title> My Website </title>
       </Helmet>
     </div>
      
      <NavigationBar/>
      <Jumbotron/>
      <Container fluid className = "container">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={(Home)}/>
        <Route exact path="/fullCV" component={(FullCV)}/>
        <Route exact path="/music" component={Music}/>
        <Route exact path="/contactme" component ={(ContactMe)}/>
        <Route component={(NoMatch)}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It works perfectly on my localhost with BrowserRouter but I need it to work with HashRouter.

Here is a sample of how I'm navigating

```
import React from 'react';
import headshot from './assets/headshot.jpg';
import headshot2 from './assets/headshot2.jpg';
import { Row, Col, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';




export const Home = () => (
  <div className = "homepage">
    <Row>
      <Col>

      
        <Router>
        <Switch>

        <Route>
        <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = "/fullCV"><h4> Full C/V and Resume </h4></Nav.Link>
        </Route>
        <Route>
        <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = "/music"><h4> Music and Music Videos </h4></Nav.Link>
        </Route>
        <Route>
        <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = "/contactme"><h4> Get in Contact with Me </h4></Nav.Link>
        </Route>

        </Switch>
        </Router>

      </Col>
       <Col>

      <img src = {headshot} height = {380} />

      </Col>
    </Row>

  </div>

)
```

It only shows the first link, Full CV and Resume, but the rest don't show up.

Comment: Is hash router working in localhost?

Comment: No, HashRouter doesn't work on localhost. The URL changes, but the page doesn't.

Comment: How are you navigating between the urls?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300429/react-app-hashrouter-not-working-on-localhost-as-well-as-github-user-page this is the exact problem, worded better. The solution they posted works for only one link. If I want to use multiple links it doesn't work. I will edit the question to show how I'm navigating on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issues as you!
How I fixed mine;

I was using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom, but switching to HashRouter fixed it for me.

```
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

return (
  <HashRouter>
    <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={(props) => <Login {...props} />} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/register"
          name="Register Page"
          render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
        />
        <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={(props) => <Page404 {...props} />} />
        <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={(props) => <Page500 {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/" name="Home" render={(props) => <DefaultLayout {...props} />} />
      </Switch>
    </React.Suspense>
  </HashRouter>
```